# Openpyxl: Determining which character in a cell value is strikethrough

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl, strikethrough

I'll first mention that I'm using Python 2.7 and Openpyxl 2.4.1

Essentially I have a sheet in a workbook that I'm cleaning. I'm going through each cell and checking if there is Strikethrough text. Assume I'm looking in Column A:

```
for i in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
    my_cell = sheet['A'+str(i)]
    if my_cell.font.strikethrough == True:
        #here's the tricky part
```

I know that it is possible to determine whether or not a cell contains strikethrough characters, but I would like to find which characters in the cell.value are strikethrough characters. I've read the docs and couldn't find too much on this. Is this possible with openpyxl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible: openpyxl does not deal with formatting below the level of the cell. You will need to write your own parser to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Charlie! I still love what you've done with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the property `Cell.font.strike`:

```
 if my_cell.font.strike ==True:
     #here's the tricky part
```

Comment: You can do it without bool just like so `if my_cell.font.strike:`. Also while this answer helps, next time try to provide working example of code and properly format it too. Read more about [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes across this when researching a solution for a more recent version of openpyxl: Starting from openpyxl version 3.1.0 it is possible to pass `richt_text=True` to the `load_workbook` function in order to enable rich text parsing.

The following code prints if part of a cell is strikethrough or not:

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import CellRichText

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Some_Workbook.xlsx", rich_text=True)
sheet = wb["Sheet1"]

for i in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
    my_cell = sheet["A"+str(i)]
    if type(my_cell.value) == CellRichText:
        for text in my_cell.value:
            if text.font.strike:
                print(text, "is strikethrough")
            else:
                print(text, "is not strikethrough")
    else:
        print(my_cell.value, "is not strikethrough")
```