# How to change the specific cell color to no fill using Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am working on the excel spreadsheet that has color in the specific cells and I would like to change those cells to "no fill" (meaning no color), Can someone help me with a python code to achieve this?

I am trying to remove only the blue color from the cells (A1, A2, B1 and F2 only) in this screenshot
[image]
in the spreadsheet.

Comment: There are libaries for python to modify coloring, please check [this](https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-add-color-to-excel-cells-using-python/) using openpyxl. Depending on your use case, VBA would also be an option. The tag [google-bigquery] does not make sense for this question.

Comment: Great, Thanks Samuel.  Hi i am working on the excel spreadsheet some cells contains strikethrough text that needs to be removed by keeping the other text as is. I have found a python script (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73087847/how-to-detect-and-filter-text-numbers-with-strikethrough-in-a-cell-containing-bo/74212517#74212517) which work, however if any cell has text length greater than ~260 character the scripts stops and need to forcefully kill the execution. Can you plz help?